# QR decomposition used for estimating condition numbers

Tags: matrix-decomposition, condition-number

I have read that the QR decomposition is often used to estimate the condition number of a matrix but I don't understand... what is the benefit of using the QR decomposition for this? Is it purely computational?

Comment: How would you propose computing the condition number?

Comment: I would do it by calculating the norm of a matrix and the norm of it's inverse and multiplying them... in particular I would use the 2-norm but am unsure if this is what the QR decomposition estimates.

Comment: Computing the norm of the inverse is expensive.

Comment: Okay... How does the qr help this calculation